# How to create a ListView scrolled to its top?

Tags: flutter

I'm a very novice Flutter programmer. I meet the following problem: the code shown below when recreates the ListView after changing data in the stream remembers the previous scroll position whereas I would like to scroll the list to its top. How could I do that?

```
class HintViewState extends State<HintView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
      stream: model.hintsStream.stream,
      initialData: [],
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot,
      ) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ||
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Eraro dum prenado de sugestoj!');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: snapshot.data!.map((word) => Padding(...)).toList(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Text("Ne estas sugestoj!");
          }
        } else {
          return Text('Stato: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use a scrollcontroller https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html

Comment: @mister_cool_beans   Yes, it is the straightfoward idea. But when should I call scrollController.jumpTo or .animateTo ? If the reconstruction is called via setState, then I can call the scroll method from the procedure where setState is invoked. But what if the rebuild is called automatically by change of the stream data?

Answer (score 1):

Create a scroll controller like as below

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Set it to the list view like as below

```
  child: ListView.builder(
          
          controller: _scrollController,
.....
```

When you want to scroll it to top, please add below code.

```
   _scrollController.animateTo(
                    _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
```

In your example, you can do like,

```
 else if (snapshot.hasData) {
_scrolltoTop();
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: snapshot.data!.map((word) => Padding(...)).toList(),
              ),
            );
          }

void _scrolltoTop(){
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
 _scrollController.animateTo(
                        _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
});
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is the straightfoward idea. But when should I call scrollController.jumtTo or .animateTo ? If the reconstruction is called via setState, then I can call the scroll method from the procedure where setState is invoked. But what if the rebuild is called automatically by change of the stream data?

Comment: Once you get the response from stream, please call this but after few seconds. Not immediately.

Comment: I have edit my answer please check it.

Comment: This idea - to call the scroll method via Future.delayed before return in the builder - also came to my head. But this looks too inelegant... The data are some typing hints, which should renew as the the user types in the input field. I've read that there is WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, which registers a function called after the interface is built. But when I tried it, it doesn't work...

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, calls only once. In your case, you are loading list in StreamBuilder. In normal case, you can add the listener in initstate to check data received via api/db or not. Once you listen this data, You can set it to the list you are showing in Listview. So in that case, you won't required to deal like this. In your case, apart from this method, no any method will get called. So, you won't have idea when data got updated.

Answer (score 0):

In a Flutter community, they explained the situation to me. And the answer is the following.

The key thing here is the parameter "key" of a widget (not a bad pun, yeah?). When during rebuilding at some place in the UI tree, a widget appears of the same type and with the same key as the previous one, then this widget is not recreated, but modified only. And in my case, evidently, modification of a ListView does not imply scrolling to a new position. "That's not a bug, that's a feature!".

One way to force complete recreation a widget when new data appear in the stream is to pass a new key. The best way to get a new key is to use the function ValueKey(...), which, evidently, computes some hash of the object passed to it and returns a key based on the hash. So, when the function is used with the data to be shown, a change of the data in the stream leads to a change of the key and, therefore, to a complete recreation of the widget, which in the case of a ListView assumes scrolling to the top.

So, the correction of the code is the following:

```
..............
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                key: ValueKey(snapshot.data),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
..............
```

But I'm not sure if in a general case, this widget only is recreated or its entire subtree. If the latter, then it might be costly.